# Temporary users to restrict db access of query?

Tags: database, database-design, node.js, postgres

I am new to database managment, and I am wondering if it is a good idea to create temporary users to restrict access to only a single table.

Like having an user named _logs can only (read?) and insert to the logs table.

I am unescaping the values and I am using environments vars, but I think it would be more secure, but is it possible and a good practise?

I am using Node.JS and Postgres if it matters.

Comment: what has permission to create 'temporary' users and who do you restrict it?

Comment: A simple script that runs before server init could create users and set their passwords in env variables (and hide the root password)

Comment: doesnt sound very temporary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very unlikely that you could restrict the access to a single table in a real application, so you would have to specify all the required tables and maintain that list.

It's a somewhat normal approach to limit things to the database user on the larger scale, such as using different roles for reporting, normal users, admins etc. depending on which layers you're handling authorization and usually when you have multiple systems sharing the database (normal / reporting is a common use case). In many cases the actual database user is always the same, and the application will then (try to) make sure that no-one is doing anything they're not supposed to.

The architecture and security requirements determine where and how you should manage authorization. For example handling government data would mean you have multiple layers of authorization to prevent any intentional or accidental data access where not allowed.

Creating a *temporary* user would be complex, and it would give very little compared to creating well thought permanent user roles. Not to mention that to create temporary users you would need to have access to an admin role that can create users. It could be a potential security problem, since often applications don't require a superuser role for normal functionality.